# Interpretation for the dictionary definition of —"ride"?

Tags: definition, interpretation

> n. (countable)
> 15. a means of being taken by a motor vehicle:
> *My ride's here.*  [<sup>Source</sup>](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/rideable)

How I should understand above definition of "ride"?(especially the usage of "being" in the definition)

Comment: It's  "unusual" phrasing for the *specific* subsense given in the example usage: ***"My ride is here"*** (the car / taxicab that's going to take me somewhere has arrived). In that sense, "a ride" more literally refers to the ***vehicle***, but the cited definition chooses to have it refer to ***the "transportation service" offered by that vehicle***. Don't sweat the details - it's a "weird" usage.

Comment: A ride was a horse… you had to ride it. The term itself just survived the transition to cars.

Comment: You really should use a better dictionary like Merriam Webster or Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: Also, you did not post that Word Reference thing correctly: **a journey or trip on a horse, etc., or on or in a vehicle.
a means of being taken by a motor vehicle**:
My ride's here.

Comment: I believe the definition is extremely abstract so as to also encompass the sentence "He is my ride tonight." It's not a clear definition even for a native speaker.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: I wasn't familiar with the horses themselves being called "rides", but I'm no equestrian. It's there in the full OED, with example *"He's a lovely ride. And he can jump anything you can see the sky over."* But the further extension being queried by OP is slightly different.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm definitely with you on your opening comment, but I cannot see the difference between the OPs strict definition & that for a horse - except a century of changed usage. [btw, I've ridden, but i'm by no means a horsey type, by a long way;)

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: The  OPs strict definition very specifically refers to ***motor vehicles***, not *animals or machines capable of being "ridden" to one's destination*. Also note that to me, *my **wheels*** refers to *my own vehicle, that I drive*, but *my **ride*** belongs to and is driven by someone else. Plus you ride horses and drive cars, not the other way around. Definitely two different "transportation mechanisms".

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Being" refers to what?

Comment: _Being taken_ = having the driver of the vehicle take you somewhere.